# Create MySQL Query Using Variable Value in Procedures

Tags: mysql, variables, procedure

I have to try using variable value on MySQL Query Procedure.
But it doesn't work. Here is my procedure:

```
SET @start=0;
SET @finish=150;

...

DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tempDate FROM tbl_temp LIMIT @start,@finish;

...
```

I just want to create query like below

```
SELECT tempDate FROM tbl_temp LIMIT 0,150;
```

So guys, what should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it with dynamic query like below

```
@qry varchar(max)
set @qry ='DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tempDate FROM tbl_temp LIMIT'+ @start+','+ @finish

exec(@qry)
```

Comment: PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; can use above code on place of exec(@qry)

Answer (score 2):

Using variables or procedure parameters in LIMIT clause is available in **MySQL 5.5**.

Othervise you need to use prepared statements. From the documentation - *Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6*. Example:

```
SET @skip=1; SET @numrows=5;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @numrows;
```

More information - [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SET start=0;
SET finish=150;

DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tempDate FROM tbl_temp LIMIT start,finish;
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, MySQL doesn't support variable on LIMIT clause as mentioned at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094

However, you can use prepared statement to solve your problem as script below:

```
SET @start=0;
SET @finish=150;
SET @query = "SELECT tempDate FROM tbl_temp LIMIT " + @start + ", " + @finish
EXEC(@query)
```